# Exclude nextjs api url from sentry events

Tags: next.js, sentry

I have nextjs app with sentry. I want to add new api route, for example `api/status`, but I want to exclude it from being sent to sentry as it will clutter logs really fast and use my qouta.

I did a small research and it seems that there is an array of urls you can exclude from being tracked. It's called `denyUrls`. [Read more](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/configuration/filtering/#decluttering-sentry). I have tried to add my url to this array, but it still tracks this url as part of events:

```
Sentry.init({
  ...
  denyUrls: [
    /api\/status/i,
  ],
  ...
});
```

Am I configuring something wrong or this array is not for the purpose of filtering everts.

If so, what's the best way to filter those? Other option I found which I will try next is `beforeSend` but it feels a bit overkill to simply exclude url. `denyUrls` feels like much better fit for what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and contacted the support for it. I am directly quoting the support here.

> The BeforeSend and DenyUrl are options to filter error events, not transactions. For transaction events, please use the tracesSampler function as described on the page: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/configuration/sampling/#setting-a-sampling-function.
> Here is an example to drop all transactions that match a certain name:

```
tracesSampler: samplingContext => {
   if(samplingContext.transactionContext.name == "GET /api/health"){
    return 0.0 // never send transactions with name GET /api/health
   }
   return 0.2 // sampling for all other transactions
   }
```

> Note that you might need to customise the function above to better match your scenario.

I hope it will help you ;)
Have a nice day.